# Detecting a new session with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session

I have a background job that grabs a user's facebook friends.

I want this background job to fire each time a signed in user starts a new browser session. I'm not sure on the technical definitions on what constitutes a "new" session for Rails, but ideally it would fire whenever the user hits the site after a period of inactivity (e.g., >30 minutes since last visit).

How can I detect a new session like this in Rails? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

This is the best I could do to solve it. I'm using a session variable. I have this method in my application_controller with a before_filter. Seems to work well but I noticed there are particular things (e.g., Pusher) that reset the session variables so definitely monitor if going with this solution. If someone has a better solution in mind, I'm all ears.

```
def call_set_facebook_friends
  if session[:new_session] == nil && signed_in?
    current_user.background_set_facebook_friends
    session[:new_session] = true
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank so for this primitive solution, it does work.  I was very surprised rack/rails session store does not have a hook for this, its very standard thing, like in Java there is an event callback/hook for application startup, session start, etc.  Security frameworks like warden/devise have hook for after signin, however if you want to ensure your code runs on first request of session (if not even logged in) doesn't seem a standard way to do it.  We tried having a custom session store that extended cookie_store but wasn't clear how to do that, get_session was getting called and sid already set

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Devise, you have a column `last_sign_in_at` in the `users` table. It can be used by your background job to check if a user has recently visited your site.